# How can I know if a JavaScript Range object is within the same paragraph?

Tags: javascript, range

I'd like to limit a user to make text selections within the same paragraph.

```
var selection = getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
```

I'd like to **validate the *range* object** so it becomes valid if the range "lives" under the same paragraph, and does not end in a possibly sibling paragraph.

How to?

See [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range) object reference.

Comment: Tried using `.startContainer` , `.endContainer` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **Selection.toString()** and check if the selection content has a new line character.

```
var range = window.getSelection().toString();
if(!/\n/.test(range)){
...
```

**EDIT**

The newline character is probably there because of the implementation of toString() method. You can see in Chromium source code this comment for example:

> // Block flow (versus inline flow) is represented by having
>   // a newline both before and after the element.

here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/editing/iterators/TextIterator.cpp&sq=package:chromium&type=cs

It's probably more a convention than something in a standard. So it may not be the most robust solution. But it's simple, can be easily validated and should have a pretty standard behavior in most cases.

Comment: So simple.. thank you! Care to elaborate where does the new line character come from ?

Comment: @wilenx. It works because by default `white-space: normal` collapses line breaks into normal spaces. But if the paragraph contains line breaks and it has `white-space: pre` it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `commonAncestorContainer` to get the deepest element which contains the entire selection, and then check if it's contained in your paragraph:

```js
paragraph.contains(range.commonAncestorContainer);
```

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p'),
    log = document.querySelector('div');
setInterval(function() {
  var selection = getSelection();
  if(selection.rangeCount) {
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    log.textContent = 'The first range selection is ' + (p.contains(range.commonAncestorContainer) ? '' : 'NOT ') + ' contained in the paragraph.';
  } else {
    log.textContent = 'No selection';
  }
}, 200);
```

```css
p { border: 1px solid; }
span { color: blue; }
b { color: lime; }
i { color: red; }
```

```html
Select some text:
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum dolor <b>sit amet, consectetur <i>adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit</i> amet ipsum mauris.</b> Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit</span>. Donec et mollis dolor.</p>
<div></div>
```